# Why Does This Not Produce an Animation?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm using SpriteKit to animate a character jump.

I know what the correct code is, but I don't know why my previous code was incorrect.

Correct:

```
let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.1, y: size.height * 0.85), duration: 0.3)
let actionFall = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.1, y: size.height * 0.3), duration: 0.3)
actionMove.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseIn
actionFall.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseOut

if CACurrentMediaTime() - time > 0.7 {
  player.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionFall]))
  time = CACurrentMediaTime()
}
```

Incorrect:

```
func jump() {
  let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.1, y: size.height * 0.85), duration: 0.3)
  let actionFall = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.1, y: size.height * 0.3), duration: 0.3)
  actionMove.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseIn
  actionFall.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseOut
  player.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionFall]))
}
if (player.position.y == size.height * 0.3){
  jump();
}
```

In the incorrect code, the character does not jump when the user taps on the screen -- the character stays at height 0.3.

Comment: I can't see anything directly wrong. Also,try keeping the same code, I have to keep re-reading it each time you edit your post (3 times in the last minute now).

Comment: What was incorrect about the incorrect bit? You need to explain why it's not correct. Also, in the "incorrect" bit you have a function next to a code snippet. In the correct bit you just have a code snippet. Can you make them similar and just show the bit that has changed.

Comment: @Fogmeister The incorrect code just has the character stay at the same height instead of jumping. Both snippets occur within the touchesEnded function, so that they are meant to occur every time the user taps the screen.

Comment: You need to make your conditions in an update loop. When you call the jump method, what really happens is that actions are created, added to the player's action queue (runAction), then you test the player position, and only in the following and subsequent frames will the player position actually change as a result of the actions (but your if check has long since passed/failed).